# Can't get values for specific options in select tag React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building broker simulator and I need to get different currency depending on which option I choose. Also I'm not sure if I need to use Form in Modal dialogue to send final info about order in different tab`

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import './select.css'
import Modal from "../popup/modal"
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Select = () => {

    
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    const [usdrub, setUsdrub] = useState(Math.random() * (64-61) + 61);
    useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setUsdrub(Math.random() * (64-61) + 61);
      }, 10000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [])

    const [rubusd, setRubusd] = useState(Math.random() * 2);
    useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setRubusd(Math.random() * 2);
      }, 10000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [])



    function changeSelect() {
        setValue(value)
    }
    const [modalActive, setModalActive] = useState(false)



    return (
        <div>
        <select onChange={changeSelect}>
        <option name="USD/RUB" value={usdrub}>USD/RUB</option>
        <option name="RUB/USD" value={rubusd}>RUB/USD</option>
        </select>
        <div className="Curr">
          <div className="Buy" name="buy"> <button className="Buy" type="btn" onClick={() => setModalActive(true)}>BUY {value + 1} </button>
          </div>
          <div className="Sell" name="sell"><button className="Sell" type="btn"  onClick={() => setModalActive(true)}>SELL {value}</button></div>
          </div>
          <Modal active={modalActive} setActive={setModalActive} price={usdrub + 1}/>
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default Select
```

Tried different imports of values, but they don't work. I get either no values (in modal dialogue I get, but it doesn't change depending on option), or only one option's values

UPD
After some corrections I have this

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import './select.css'
import Modalbuy from "../popup/Modalbuy"
import Modalsell from "../popup/Modalsell"
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Select = () => {

    
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    const [usdrub, setUsdrub] = useState(Math.random() * (64-61) + 61);
    useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setUsdrub(Math.random() * (64-61) + 61);
      }, 10000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [])

    const [rubusd, setRubusd] = useState(Math.random() * 2);
    useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setRubusd(Math.random() * 2);
      }, 10000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [])



    function changeSelect(event) {
        setValue(event.target.value)
    }
    const [modalBuyActive, setModalBuyActive] = useState(false)
    const [modalSellActive, setModalSellActive] = useState(false)



    return (
        <div>
        <select value = {value} onChange={changeSelect}>
        <option selected></option>
        <option name="USD/RUB" value={usdrub}>USD/RUB</option>
        <option name="RUB/USD" value={rubusd}>RUB/USD</option>
        </select>
        <div className="Curr">
          <div className="Buy" name="buy"> <button className="Buy" type="btn" onClick={() => setModalBuyActive(true)}>BUY {value + 1} </button>
          </div>
          <div className="Sell" name="sell"><button className="Sell" type="btn"  onClick={() => setModalSellActive(true)}>SELL {value}</button></div>
          </div>
          <Modalbuy active={modalBuyActive} setActive={setModalBuyActive} price={value + 1}/>
          <Modalsell active={modalSellActive} setActive={setModalSellActive} price={value}/>
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default Select
```

Modalbuy.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./modal.css";

const Modalbuy = ({active, setActive,price}) => {
  
    return (
        <div className={active ? "modal active" : "modal"} onClick={() => setActive(false)}>
          <div className="modal__content" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
            <header>Make order</header>
            <p>BUY {price}</p>
            <input placeholder="Volume"></input>
            <div>
              <button>Ok</button>
              <button>Cancel</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modalbuy;
```

Modalsell.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./modal.css";

const Modalsell = ({active, setActive,price}) => {
    return (
        <div className={active ? "modal active" : "modal"} onClick={() => setActive(false)}>
          <div className="modal__content" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
            <header>Make order</header>
            <p>SELL {price}</p>
            <input placeholder="Volume"></input>
            <div>
              <button>Ok</button>
              <button>Cancel</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modalsell;
```

Timer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'


const Timer = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
  

  
    return (      
      <div className="clock">
        {time}      
      </div>
    );
  };


  export default Timer;
```

Trading.js

```
import React from "react";
import Timer from "./Timer";
import Select from "./select_curr/Select";

const Trading = () => {
    return (
        <div>
        <Timer/>
        <Select/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Trading;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Page from './components/page/page'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Page/>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with the `changeSelect` function called on the `onChange` event of the `<select>` element.

1. First add value attribute on `<select>` tag

```
<select value={value} onChange={changeSelect}>
```

2. Rewrite the `changeSelect` function like below

```
 function changeSelect(event) {
        setValue(event.target.value)
 }
```

Here, the changeSelect function sets the value of the `<select>` tag to the value of the selected option by `event.target.value`

Comment: For some reason, in console it shows that 'event' is outdated

Comment: What is the react version currently you are working with?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to add (event) argument) But after corrections, my styles broke and modal dialogue appears on main page on same level as other tags

Comment: Also made some grammar fixes, now its working) But when I just browse the tab, the default values are {values + 1 } which gives literally 1 and second button returns no values. I guess I need to set some option as default

Comment: why style broked for modal, wasn't it working fine before?

Comment: Yeah, I think setting a default value will work. Or showing the modal conditionally based on the true state of modalActive

Comment: Ok, "selected" parameter kinda works, but it doesn't get values from option, it just returns "BUY 1" and "SELL"

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-water-26fhuk?file=/src/component.js isn't it working exptected

Comment: Well, I went the easy way and made a new component (I created ModalSell component and ModalBuy component for every button). You have a problem because I think I didn't show here my other created components. I can transfer them here I guess. Now my problem is I need to get values from Modal dialogues and sort them in the table in another component.